# momentJS get UTC timestamp

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Folks, I am unable to get the UTC timestamp using the momentjs.  Hope someone can point me in the right direction

```
var start = Date.now();
var utc = moment.utc(start).toDate();
```

or

```
var utc = moment.utc().toDate();
Tue Nov 11 2014 13:45:13 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Returns the EST timezone I am in, not UTC.  How do i get the Javascript Date in UTC?

If I do

```
var utc= moment.utc();
console.log(utc);
```

output is

```
 { _useUTC: true,
  _isUTC: true,
  _l: undefined,
  _i: undefined,
  _f: undefined,
  _d: Tue Nov 11 2014 13:43:21 GMT-0500 (EST) }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `start`?

Comment: `var start = Date.now();`

Comment: You're looking for a timestamp - not a formatted date?  Then use `.valueOf()` instead of `.toDate()`

Comment: I am looking for a formatted date, and obviously its not working.

Answer (score 34):

Simplest answer from the comments :

```
moment.utc().valueOf()
```

Gives UTC timestamp

Comment: Or use:  moment.utc().format("X") - for uniх timestamp in seconds

Answer (score 10):

```
var moment = require('moment');

// timestamp with UTC time
console.log(moment.utc().format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss z'));

// or via the date object
console.log(moment.utc().toDate().toUTCString());
```

Comment: This does not work as specified in the question.  My output for console.log(moment.utc().toDate()); is `Tue Nov 11 2014 14:02:10 GMT-0500 (EST)`

Comment: How do i get the JavaScript Date of UTC??

Comment: Extremely frustrating... This does not work: `var utc = moment.utc().valueOf();
    console.log('moment.utc()',moment(utc).toDate());`

Comment: Updated my answer.  You can use format to get what you're looking for.

Comment: but I need the .toDate() to stick the result into Mongo

Comment: I need `"lastModified" : "Tue Nov 11 2014 19:20:38 z"` to look like a dateTime object for mongo.  how? :)

Comment: Have you tried adding a record with a date object and then using the Mongo shell to check it?

Comment: Thats exactly what im doing :(

Comment: `var utc = moment.utc().valueOf();
    console.log(moment.utc(utc).toDate());` does NOT work

Comment: Started a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873200/momentjs-getting-javascript-date-in-utc

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to know how to get the number of SECONDS, not milliseconds.

In moment.js 1.6.0, use this if you want the [timestamp in seconds](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/):

```js
moment.utc().unix()
```

@Charles Foster's answer deals with [milliseconds](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/), which has been around since moment.js 1.0.0:

```js
moment.utc().valueOf()
```