# Parsing JSON - Converting a Mongoose time stamp into EPOCH time

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, date, mongoose

When I query my REST API, I get a JSON response like this:

```
{"litres":50,"nodeID":"2","location":"TESTDEPLOY","_id":"571645da91de00136612811b","__v":0,"time":"2016-04-19T14:51:06.489Z"}
```

Part of this response is the time stamp : `"time":"2016-04-19T14:51:06.489Z"`

Is there any way I can change this time stamp into Epoch time while parsing the JSON, as I want to feed it into a charting tool that uses EPOCH time.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873200/momentjs-getting-javascript-date-in-utc) helpful as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "Epoch" time? JavaScript has a Date object, which might be what you mean, but right now it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) you may convert the time field like:

```js
var inputJson = {"litres":50,"nodeID":"2","location":"TESTDEPLOY","_id":"571645da91de00136612811b","__v":0,"time":"2016-04-19T14:51:06.489Z"};

var m = moment(inputJson.time, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ');

var ts = moment(inputJson.time).valueOf();

var s = m.format("M/D/YYYY H:mm");

document.write('ts: ' + ts + '  s: ' + s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) You would use this library to convert the time value after you received the response.

Something like:

```
var moment = require('moment');

//later in code
responseValue.time = moment(responseValue.time).valueOf(); //to get a value like 1415806206570
```

`moment(String)` creates a new "moment object" that parses the given value. `.valueOf()` give the time in milliseconds since the unix epoch.

Comment: How would he use that library to parse that value? Without the example, this is basically a link to the answer.