# Storing time with offset to be referenced later

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, time

What I want to do in the end:
* Check if current UTC time on Node server is after a user's local time.

In Node (Expressjs) I'm fetching some user data from Facebook. They only consistently give me a time offset (like -8) and a locale (like en_US)

If I naively check `utcTime + offset >= userTime` it will be off sometimes based on daylight savings.

What is the recommended way of dealing with this?

I'm storing data in Postgres if that makes any difference? It has some time functions.

Comment: for date manipulation, use http://momentjs.com/, it makes everything easier

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). Great library when working with dates and times, especially the [UTC support](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

For you, take the given time and turn it into UTC time, then compare.

`var nodeTime = moment.utc(serverValue);
var facebookTime = moment.utc(facebookValue);
nodeTime.isAfter(facebookTime); // => true or false`

Comment: This does not detect daylight savings changes.

Comment: Have a look at the momentjs documentation. There are queries for that as well, [isDST()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/) Maybe they will be useful for your use-case.

If you are really concerned, just convert to a timestamp and compare those milliseconds. In that way the timezone will not matter. See this answer for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873200/momentjs-getting-javascript-date-in-utc/26890639#26890639