# Moment js UTC date comparison

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I go about comparing `new Date().toUTCString()` to a say `Wed, 03 Oct 2018 01:33:29 GMT` in moment?

I've tried `moment(Wed, 03 Oct 2018 01:33:29 GMT).isBefore(moment(new Date().toUTCString()))` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think moment converts the date to local date time when you create moment. So you need to get the utc value form moment and then compare it. [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873200/momentjs-getting-javascript-date-in-utc) lin which does that.

Comment: Can you provide an example? How do you want this conversion?

Comment: `moment(Wed, 03 Oct 2018 01:33:29 GMT)` is not even valid syntax - are you missing quotes here?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have explained, the comparison is working for me. Check the snippet. FYI, you need to use `''` while creating a moment object from the string.

```js
$(() => {
  var a = moment('Wed, 03 Oct 2018 01:33:29 GMT');
  var b = moment(new Date().toUTCString());
  console.log(a.isBefore(b));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it as follows:

```
moment('Thu Oct 04 2018 07:35:54 GMT+0530 (IST)').isBefore(moment())

moment('Wed, 03 Oct 2018 01:33:29 GMT').isBefore(moment())
```

This should return you value. (true/false)

Comment: does `moment()` by default return UTC? then what's the purpose of `moment.utc()`?

Comment: Basically ``moment`` returns date to localeString with current timezone info. Above code will give you correct result if you use the date in this format in from any timezone.